# Can you use two dictionary values ​to replace text in Python?

Tags: python

What should I do if the output of my code has changed only two texts

```
dict_data = [{'test 2': '333','m': 'mm'}, {'sss': 'n','help': '5'}]

texts = ["test 2 text m and text", "text help sss"]

for text in texts:
    for dict_data_a in dict_data:
        out = " ".join(dict_data_a.get(ele, ele) for ele in text.split())
        print(out)
```

Something that waits for the output

```
333 2 text mm and text
text 5 n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1st problem

You have a double loop. So you have 4 combinations: 1st text with 1st dict, 1st text with 2nd dict, 2nd text with 1st dict, ...

2 of them are the ones you wanted. 2 others are.

Here, I surmise that you wanted to replace words of the 1st text with 1st dict, and 2nd text with 2nd dict.

So you need 1 loop. But iterating both list (text and dict) at the same time.

Simple (to understand) version

```py
dict_data = [{'test 2': '333','m': 'mm'}, {'sss': 'n','help': '5'}]

texts = ["test 2 text m and text", "text help sss"]

for i in range(len(texts)):
    text=texts[i]
    dict_data_a=dict_data[i]
    out = " ".join(dict_data_a.get(ele, ele) for ele in text.split())
    print(out)
```

Or, more pythonesque one

```py
dict_data = [{'test 2': '333','m': 'mm'}, {'sss': 'n','help': '5'}]
texts = ["test 2 text m and text", "text help sss"]

for text,dict_data_a in zip(texts, dict_data):
    out = " ".join(dict_data_a.get(ele, ele) for ele in text.split())
    print(out)
```

### 2nd problem

You are basing your replacement on words. Yet you have one replacement that cannot fit a word, since it is made of 2 words (test 2).

You can't not just replace one substring by another with `replace`, because then you would be, for example, replacing all `m` by `mm`, even those that are just letters in a word. For example `looming` would be replaced by `loomming`.

So for that, there are certainly many solutions, but the easiest one would be using regex, I think.

```py
import re
dict_data = [{'test 2': '333','m': 'mm'}, {'sss': 'n','help': '5'}]
texts = ["test 2 text m and text", "text help sss"]

for text,dict_data_a in zip(texts, dict_data):
    out = text
    for org,rep in dict_data_a.items():
        out = re.sub(r'(?<!\w)'+org+'(?!\w)', rep, out)
    print(out)
```

Here we replace each key by its associated value, but using a reg ex, consisting of the key (org), prefixed by a "look-behind" `(?<!\z)` that make the patter matches only occurrence of org that are not preceded by a letter (`\w`). And suffixed by a "look-ahred" `(?!\w)` that also forces the pattern to match only occurrence of org that are not followed immediately by a letter.

So "m one" will be replace by "mm one". "two m three" by "two mm three", "four m" by "four mm". But "many or some boom" won't turn into "mmany or somme boomm"

Answer (score 1):

*Can you use two dictionary values ​to replace text in Python?*  **Yes**

You could use `str.replace`

```
for text in texts:
    for d in dict_data:
        for k,v in d.items():
            text = text.replace(k, v)
    print(text)
```

Output:

```
333 text mm and text
text 5 n
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach: It is easier to deal with one dictionary, than multiple ones, so I use `collections.ChainMap` to turn a list of dictionary (`dict_data`) into a single dictionary (`replacements`). Then it is a matter of writing a simple function to transform all the old text to new ones (`replace_all`).

```py
import collections

def replace_all(text, lookup_dict):
    for old_value, new_value in lookup_dict.items():
        text = text.replace(old_value, new_value)
    return text

dict_data = [{'test 2': '333','m': 'mm'}, {'sss': 'n','help': '5'}]
texts = ["test 2 text m and text", "text help sss"]

replacements = collections.ChainMap(*dict_data)
new_texts = [replace_all(text, replacements) for text in texts]
print("\n".join(new_texts))
```

#### Notes

- `replacements` behave like a single, combined dictionary
- The `print` statement is to produce the output

#### Output

```
333 text mm and text
text 5 n
```